# How to correctly set variable in .bss and make it init. value = 0

Tags: debugging, gdb, init

I make my own makefile myself.
I get some strange result from the program and so i just simply insert some easy variable (test)to that. 
I would like to ask why test not = 100 ??????
under what circumstance would it happen?

this is the result show in gdb

```
74    __CRC_CLK_ENABLE();
(gdb) step
182 test = 100;
(gdb) p test
$1 = 236 '\354'
```

I am running on linux and this is my first time to use command line and make my own makefile.
i have working on stm32 projects. 
My problem are: 
1)i have some variable and init to zero , it falls into .bss section , however once i debug it and find it is not zero case
And when i init it to non-zero, it falls into .data section and oncei step it it comes out to be non-zero value
2)Once i start program using gdb , it doesnt fall in main(), why?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwV8P.png)

and this is my linker file:

```
  _sidata = .;
.data : /* LMA address is _sidata (in FLASH) */
{
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .; /* data section VMA address */
    *(.data*)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;
} >ram

/* Uninitialized data section (zeroed out by startup code) */
.bss :
{
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sbss = .;
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;
} >ram AT >flash
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
(gdb) step
182 test = 100;
(gdb) p test
$1 = 236 '\354'
```

you are stopped *before* line 182 has executed. The value of `test` is likely uninitialized, and just happens to be 236.

If you want to see the value 100, you need to execute `next` command so you are looking at the value of `test` *after* it has been assigned.